# Java 7 to 8 JAXB List issue

Tags: java, jaxb

I am upgrading our system from Java 7 to 8 and I noticed a strange issue. I read some category tree data from Ebay using their commerce API and unmarshal using JAXB. The specific call I use is similar to their example on [this page](http://developer.ebaycommercenetwork.com/docs/read/API_Use_Cases#35) which is http://sandbox.api.ebaycommercenetwork.com/publisher/3.0/rest/CategoryTree?apiKey=78b0db8a-0ee1-4939-a2f9-d3cd95ec0fcc&visitorUserAgent&visitorIPAddress&trackingId=7000610&categoryId=0&showAllDescendants=true.

Category Tree Response:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="CategoryTreeResponse", namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
public class CategoryTreeResponse{

    private EbayCategory category;

    @XmlElement(namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
    public EbayCategory getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(EbayCategory category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

}
```

Ebay Category Object:

```
public class EbayCategory {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String categoryURL;
    private String contentType;
    private List<EbayCategory> categories;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId){
        this.id = categoryId;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
    public String getName() {
        if(name == null){
            return "";
        }
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="categoryURL", namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
    public String getCategoryURL() {
        return categoryURL;
    }
    public void setCategoryURL(String categoryURL) {
        this.categoryURL = categoryURL;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }
    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="categories", namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
    @XmlElement(name="category", namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
    public List<EbayCategory> getCategories() {
        if(categories == null){
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        }
        return categories;
    }
    public void setCategories(List<EbayCategory> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

When I unmarshal the data, the EbayCategory.categories list is always null even though there is clearly data. There is no exception or other message from what I can see, it just does nothing. In Java 7, this worked perfectly. Was there some change between versions, or is there something that I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in Java 8, performing operations in the getter when annotated with a JAXB annotation will cause issues. When the getCategories() method is changed to only return the local value, everything works just fine.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="categories", namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
@XmlElement(name="category", namespace="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com")
public List<EbayCategory> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}
```